# Specific Text need Surface in order to be light in Dark mode

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a sample which I use Jetpack compose in it : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/SampleCompose

Here is my Theme for the application which is the default by Android Studio :

```
@Composable
fun ComposeTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable() () -> Unit) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Base on this when I am in dark mode, Text's color are light. as an example Texts in my List items:

```
@Composable
fun VerticalListItem(item: Poster, callback: OnClickListener) {
    val typography = MaterialTheme.typography
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp)
            .clickable(onClick = { callback.onClick(item) })
    ) {
        ImageView(url = item.poster, height = 150.dp)
        Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Text(
            text = item.name,
            style = typography.h6
        )
        Text(
            text = item.release,
            style = typography.body2
        )
        Text(
            text = item.playtime,
            style = typography.subtitle2
        )
    }
}
```

I have a DetailView as follow :

```
@Composable
fun DetailView(item: Poster, pressOnBack: () -> Unit, sendNotification: () -> Unit) {
    val typography = MaterialTheme.typography
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .fillMaxHeight()
    ) {
        Box {
            ImageView(url = item.poster, height = 420.dp)
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                tint = Color.White,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(12.dp)
                    .clickable(onClick = pressOnBack)
            )
        }
        Spacer(Modifier.height(8.dp))
        Button(
            onClick = sendNotification,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        ) {
            Text(text = "DeepLink")

        }
        Spacer(Modifier.height(8.dp))
        Surface {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                text = item.description,
                style = typography.body2
            )
        }
    }
}
```

As you see Text here is surrounded by `Surface`, otherwise it will be Dark in Dark mode. Why is that? Why my other Texts for instance in `VerticalListItem` do not need `Surface`? I also have a Button in `DetailView` which is showing Light in Dark mode. I can not understand why this specific Text need `Surface`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tint is derived from the parent content color. The box is not a surface, has no background so the content color is indifferent. Anyway you don't have to wrap it in a surface, just set the color for the text:

```
MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
```

or

```
color = contentColorFor(background)
```

Comment: It is not wrapped in a Box rather a Column. Box is closed after Icon. Same as `VerticalListItem`. BTW thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @Ali it is the same problem. If the color cannot be derived you'll have to specify it. You can even use contentColorFor()

Comment: @Ali compose the DetailView in the same place where you have the VerticalListItem composable and see if the color works without surface. If yes the problem is in the parent composable

Comment: But for instance why my Button do not need to specify that?

Comment: @Ali maybe because they already have the default color set, buttons use primary/onPrimary i think and for text depends on where you put it